# Tooling available to automatically resolve and order TypeScript dependencies with (or without) _references.ts?

Tags: javascript, dependencies, gruntjs, typescript, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to grok the new ["_references.ts" workflow](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/12/05/announcing-typescript-0-9-5.aspx), and feel like I'm missing something w/r/t using/combining multiple files (no external modules) and still producing correct "dependency-ordered" .js code. Starting with the standard "greeter" template example in Visual Studio 2013, I:

1. refactor the Greeter class to a file named greeter.ts
2. select the "Combine JavaScript output" option in the project property page, replacing this as the new script target in the HTML
3. create a "_references.ts" file and **manually** add, in the correct order, references to my two source files, first "greeter.ts" and then "app.ts"

This compiles and runs fine. Thanks to the "all .ts files reference all other ones in the project" feature [available as of TypeScript 0.9.1](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Known%20breaking%20changes%20between%200.8%20and%200.9), I never had to explicitly reference "greeter.ts" from "app.ts". Thinking ahead to a large project, this will be very convenient.

BUT, it's only half the story (unless I'm missing something...new to JavaScript, too, so that's very likely). What about tooling to automatically order the list in "_references.ts" (e.g. auto-generation)? Seems to me that Visual Studio (TypeScript compiler?) already knows the correct ordering. I'm looking to port a C# application with many hundreds of classes, and it would be a daunting task to order these manually. Is there a "planned" feature to do this in 1.0, or should I be looking at 3rd party tools? I found [grunt-ts](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-ts)...am I on the right track?

Comment: This may get an answer on the codeplex site for TypeScript if you asked there. The feature isn't on their roadmap: http://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Roadmap

Comment: Posted here: https://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/491988

Answer (score 3):

grunt-ts has had support for `reference.ts` file creation since before visual studio supported it : https://github.com/basarat/grunt-ts#reference-file-generation

You can see a sample workflow here : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-6vT7xgE4Y&hd=1

Comment: Thanks - will check it out in more detail.

Comment: Looks pretty useful - nice work. I see you use WebStorm in your example; any thoughts on deploying grunt/grunt-ts as a VS plugin/extension?

Comment: grunt-ts just seems to alphabetically dump out a list of all the files in my project tree. it's not doing any kind of analysis right? I realize this could be extremely difficult to do - if not impossible, but at least figuring out the correct order for inheritance prototypes would be nice

Comment: `it's not doing any kind of analysis right ` yup. It would be nice but not planned.

Comment: How you guys are dealing with the fact that it orders the file alphabetically? Trying to migrate a big angularJs app. I am having to put the .controller() on the same file as the Ctrl.

Comment: `I am having to put the .controller() on the same file as the Ctrl.` I recommend that.